# Installation is getting failed while installing MSSQL cluster in Kubernetes setup (Ubuntu-18.04)

Tags: sql-server, docker, kubernetes

I am facing the below error while installing MSSQL cluster in Kubernetes setup.

**Error:**

Starting cluster deployment.

Cluster controller endpoint is available at XX.XX.XX.XX:30080.
Cluster control plane is ready.

```
[Request 112e9901-602d-4400-89cf-203df5db34f1] Cluster mssql-cluster does not exist. 
Data pool resources cleanup failed System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[Pod: master][Container: mssql-server] The provisioner has timed out.
```

**Provisioning for cluster 'mssql-cluster' has failed**

**Cluster deployment failed. Cluster State: Error.**

Collecting the logs for cluster 'mssql-cluster'.
Collecting logs for containers...

```
Data pool resources cleanup failed System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=10; handshake=14994;  ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out

Data pool resources cleanup failed System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=10; handshake=14994;  ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out

Data pool resources cleanup failed System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No such host is known

Data pool resources cleanup failed System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No such host is known

[Errno 111] Connection refused : Failed to collect cluster logs after retrying for 2 minute(s).. More detail can be found in the mssqlctl.log file
Failed to copy cluster logs
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

**Can you please provide you help to resolve this issue.**

Answer (score 0):

Those errors: `Cluster mssql-cluster does not exist. The server was not found or was not accessible` looks like problem with deployment and configuration.

So please follow those guidelines like:

- During deploying you can use one of the [default configuration/custom configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/deployment-guidance?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#configfile),
- [Monitor the deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/deployment-guidance?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#monitor),
- [Retrieve endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/deployment-guidance?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#endpoints),
- [Verify the cluster status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/deployment-guidance?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#status),
- [Kubernetes troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/cluster-troubleshooting-commands?view=sqlallproducts-allversions),

Hope this help.

Comment: These documents has resolved my initial issue. But now the cluster setup is been waiting for a long time.

BDC & Master pool is waiting for a long time (more than 2 hours)

Comment: Please provide more information. What you did at the moment deployments, and configuration yaml)